# Getting error on python while transferring data from SQL server to snowflake

Tags: python, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting below error

> query = command % processed_params TypeError: not all arguments
>   converted during string formatting

I am trying to pull data from SQL server and then inserting it into Snowflake 
my below code

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import snowflake.connector
driver = 'SQL Server'
server = 'tanmay'
db1 = 'testing'
tcon = 'no'
uname = 'sa'
pword = '123'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', 
                      host=server, database=db1, trusted_connection=tcon,
                      user=uname, password=pword)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Admin_tbldbbackupdetails")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
#for row in rows:
 # #data = [(row[0], row[1],row[2], row[3],row[4], row[5],row[6], row[7])]
print (rows[0])  
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()

connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user='****',password='****',account='*****')

cursor2 = connection.cursor()
cursor2.execute("USE WAREHOUSE FOOD_WH")
cursor2.execute("USE DATABASE Test")
sql1="INSERT INTO CN_RND.Admin_tbldbbackupdetails_ip"
"(id,dbname, dbpath, backupdate, backuptime, backupStatus, FaildMsg, Backupsource)"
"values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor2.execute(sql1,*rows[0])
```

Comment: What does your print (rows[0]) print?

Comment: data retrieve from SQL Server.

Comment: I meanm what _exactly_ does it print. Does the number of elements and the structure of them match the query?

Comment: structure is not matching data which is generated from SQL is in list

Comment: Can you post the print output? I suspect the shape of it doesn't match what the query expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obviously string parsing error.
You missed to provide parameter to `%s` printout.

If you cannot fix it step back and try another approach.
Use another script to achieve the same and get back to you bug tomorrow :-)

My script is doing pretty much the same:

```
1. Connect to SQL Server
    -> fetchmany
        -> multipart upload to s3
            -> COPY INTO Snowflake table
```

Details are here: [Snowpipe-for-SQLServer](https://github.com/pydemo/Snowpipe-for-SQLServer/blob/master/snowpipe.py)